# how mount userdata.img or userdata-qemu.img in osx

Tags: android, macos, mount, drive, qemu

Disk Utility in OSX easily mounts an SD Card image as a device, but not so the other img files.

I want to get the database I just created in the Android Emulator off the drive and into my osx file system.

I updated my system with qemu using macports but no combination I try succeeds. Anyone figured out how to do this?

Obviously one way I can do this is run the app on my phone than mount the phone as a USB drive. But I don't wanna. I wanna get it off the drive the emulator uses :-)

Thanks in advance, folks.

Michael

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use adb to pull the database off of the emulator?  I actually just answered a similar question... here it was:

The database for a specific app lives in `/data/data/[packagename]/databases`

The packagename is the package you define in your manifest, for instance `/data/data/org.vimtips.supacount/databases/counts.db`.

You can view it with `adb shell` and type `sqlite3 /data/data/org.vimtips.supacount/databases/counts.db`

Or you can pull it from the device to look at it with a third party utility, with a command like `adb pull /data/data/org.vimtips.supacount/databases/counts.db .`.

Comment: good answer, synic. That helps me immediately, as does mounting the actual Nexus device as a USB Drive. But I'd still like to know how to mount my image file. It can be done on Ubuntu etc with loop0 but OSX is structured differently than Linux. Thank you! That was a BIG help to me.

Comment: You may be able to do it with "Disk Utility".  I can't remember the exact location, but you can mount ISOs with it.  It's one of the menu options... something like "Mount Disk Image".

Answer (score 0):

Use the File Explorer in DDMS (from Eclipse SDK), you can see the whole file system there and download/upload files to the desired place. That way you don't have to mount and deal with images, and no adb commands either